# How to ignore duplicate value in json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have a json like this and i want to ignore duplicate value and print it on console.How can i do this through loop ?For example here I6 is coming 2 times but when it come to second time than i want to ignore it and print next value.

```
[{
    "phname": "I6"
  }, {
    "phname": "I6"
  }, {
    "phname": "I7"
  }, {
    "phname": "SAM1"
  }, {
    "phname": "SAM1"
  }, {
    "phname": "SAM3"
  },
]
```

Comment: First, you parse the JSON. Then the question is how to remove duplicate objects according to a property key from the resulting array. Which has already been repeatedly answered here.

Comment: Need to find a better dup; the previous one was underscore-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.

```js
var data = [ { "phname":"I6" }, { "phname":"I6" }, { "phname":"I7" }, { "phname":"SAM1" }, { "phname":"SAM1" }, { "phname":"SAM3" }]

data.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.phname]) {
    console.log(e);
    this[e.phname] = true;
  }
}, {})
```